# std::map with string or struct key

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

How do i memory map a std:map of key value of type struct or string in c++?
Is this possible to do so? Right now i'm doing memory mapping with a map with key value int, but since max range of int is limited and the max size of the key value in my program is around 10^24, i'm stuck. so by either using key type as struct or string can i solve this problem?

```
 int p0, p1, p2;
map<int,int> p0obj, p1obj, p2obj, size_p; int count = 0; 

                    float d0, d1, d2;                      
                    float a0 = a[p0];  
                    float b0 = b[p0]; 
                    float a1 = a[p1]; 
                    float b1 = b[p1];
                    float a2 = a[p2]; 
                    float b2 = b[p2];
                    if(d0>0 && d1>0 && d2>0) {
                        int key = d0+max_d*(d1+max_d*(d2+max_d*(a0+max_c*(b0+max_c*(a1+max_c*(b1+max_c*(a2+max_c*b2)))))));
        //std::string key = std::to_string(k);
                        p0obj[key] = p0; p1obj[key] = p1; p2obj[key] = p2; size_p[key]++;
                        oa << p0obj; oa << p1obj; oa << p2obj; oa << size_p;
                        std::cout<<"key="<<key<<std::endl;
                    }
                } 
            }
```

Comment: In your code the key type is `std::string`, are you saying that code doesn't work (if so then how), or did you mean *value* type not *key* type in your question? In your code the value type is `int`.

Comment: i haven't tried to run with string as key. i wanted to know it if string or struct in key works.

Comment: Please don't use the term "[memory mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O)", it has very different semantics. You should use your struct as the key indeed and define a proper `operator<`

Comment: Technically, `string` works as a key without any (technical) issue. `struct` works as a key if you have `operator<` defined for it. However, whether this is practical for you, meaning that your key fulfills its purpose of uniquely identifying the value, I don't really see based on your question

Comment: so that means i can use struct and string for key value both? i have lost my another file where the saved map values were... so i can't test this new changes right now.

Comment: Could you reduce to a [mcve] of the problem you actually have?  It seems to be hidden amongst all the irrelevant arithmetic (BTW, what's all that `sqrt()` for, where you'd be much better off with `std::hypot()`?)

Comment: what do you mean with "memory mapping" ?

Comment: memory mapped file.

Comment: This isn't code for a memory mapped file, you are mixing up your terminology. This is simply serialization of data structures to a file.

Comment: i would suggest you to remove "memory mapping" from the question. It adds double confusion because, the question is actually about using a map, and even if you do some memory mapping it isnt relevant for the question (if i am not mistaken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to use a bunch of `float`s as the key in a map.

You can do it either by wrapping them as a [`tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) or define a more meaningful `struct` type:

```
#include <map>

struct MyKey {
    float d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2;

    bool operator < (const MyKey& o) const {
        return std::tie(d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2) < std::tie(o.d0, o.d1, o.d2, o.a0, o.b0, o.a1, o.b1, o.a2, o.b2);
    }
};

struct MyValue {
    float p0, p1, p2;
};

std::map<MyKey, MyValue> pobj;
```

To insert into this map:

```
    pobj.insert({{d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2}, {p0, p1, p2}});
```

Not sure however what you would do with such a map. Searching by floats will probably not work out well. But looking up a subspace with e.g. [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) might still be useful.

```
    auto it = pobj.lower_bound({d0, d1, d2, a0, b0, a1, b1, a2, b2});
    if (it != end(pobj)) {
        const MyKey& key = it->first;
        const MyValue& value = it->second;
        std::cout << "found: " << value.p0 << " " << value.p1 << " " << value.p2 << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that `float`s rarely comare equal, hence adding a value for "the same" key can go wrong

Comment: @DineshLama - see my edit. Use `find`, but better yet `lower_bound` or `upper_bound` since `find` requires an exact match (difficult to achieve with floats).

Comment: actually instead of float int also can be used their. should i change any line above after if i change float to int?

Comment: Using integers in the key instead of floats is a very good idea, because you don't have to deal with inexact comparison during searching.